# MVC data annotation on client side conditional

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

i have a form wherein there is conditional textboxes.i have used mvc dataannotation client side on dropdown change i hide two textboxes data validation error is not fired but in controller i get model error in `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.How can i do condtional handling of data annotation in client side only.I dont want to use fullproof validation or other third party.
i tried removing the data-val-* attributes using jquery still getting error in controller.refer image if i select asset type laptop then sim plan and price is hidden dataannotation dont fire which is correct but get error on controller.
[image: formimage]

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Make")]
public string Make { get; set; } 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Model")] 
public string Model { get; set; } 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Sim Plan")] 
public string SimPlan { get; set; } 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Price")] 
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: will you share model class and view page??

Comment: [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Sim Plan")]
        public string SimPlan { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Price")]
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }

Comment: You are getting the errors, because even though those fields are hidden in the form, they are likely being posted as part of the form submit.  If you don't post them with the form, then your ModelState should be valid.

So it kind of depends on how you are posting the form.

Comment: Why would you not want to use a  [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar attribute so all this is handled out of the box and you get both client side and server side validation? And you can always write your own `[RequiredIf]` attribute that implements `IClientValidatable`

Answer (score 0):

there's a much better way to add conditional validation rules in MVC3. Have your model inherit IValidatableObject and implement the Validate method:

```
public class Person : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSenior { get; set; }
    public Senior Senior { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (IsSenior && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Senior.Description)) 
            yield return new ValidationResult("Description must be supplied.");
    }
}
```

see more of a description at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to manually clear validation error which u have not used in your view than i would suggest you clear them before checking modelstate.
Ex:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Model objModel )
    {
        foreach (string Key in ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    if ((Key.Equals("Email")) || (Key.Equals("Password")))
                    {
                        ModelState[Key].Errors.Clear();
                    }
                }
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                { 
                       //Do the work
                }
   }
```

In the above example i have passed the values in Model and i didn't pass any value for Email and password, so in controller i am clearing those Key which is present in ModelState.